# What do these cipher algorithm symbols mean?

Tags: reference, encryption

Please take a look at the following image…

[image: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:BlowfishFFunction.svg]

There are two symbols in this image.

I learned from [Wikipedia's “List of logic symbols”](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_logic_symbols) the symbol “⊕” stands for “XOR”, but what does that cross in square symbol mean? Does that mean “XOR” too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**XOR**

[image: XOR]

Means: combine the two inputs using XOR. So, this symbol indeed can be read as “⊕”.

**Addition**

[image: Addition]

Means: combine the two inputs using addition. This symbol indeed can be read as “+”.

**Nota Bene**

In the image you're asking about, it is noted that the S-boxes take 8 bit (= unsigned char) input and return 32 bits (= unsigned int)… which means the cipher expects you to do the addition and XOR on unsigned integers.

[image: Graphic]

Comment: It is clear. Thanks for your answer after two month.

Answer (score 1):

The plus in a box is addition mod 2<sup>32</sup> (actually, I don't remember for sure -- it could be mod 2<sup>32</sup>-1, but it's addition in any case).